# How to feed Jacobian to scikits.odes.odeint

Tags: python, ode, scikits

I am using `scikits.odes.odeint` to solve a relatively large system of ODEs (40 variables, 100 kinetic parameters). I want to speed up the process by supplying a jacobian to the solver. However, I do not know how to best define the jacobian for this purpose and supply it to the solver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very basic symbolic Jacobion but it works for most ODE solvers.

```
import sympy as sp

def rhs(t, y):
return [y[0],2*y[1]]


def jacob(t, y):
  ydot = rhs(t,y)
  J =  sp.Matrix(ydot).jacobian(y)
  J_func = sp.lambdify((t, y) , J)
  return J_func
```

There is a more in depth guide [here](https://www.sympy.org/scipy-2017-codegen-tutorial/notebooks/32-chemical-kinetics-symbolic-construction.html).